# cloud composer airflow plugin usage

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, flask-appbuilder

I am just starting with airflow plugins and am a bit confused.

I am running it as a managed service using Cloud Composer on GCP (composer-1.13.4-airflow-1.10.12)

I wrote the plugin as per the docs but don't really know how to 'use' it

```
class TestAppBuilderBaseView(AppBuilderBaseView):
    @expose("/test")
    def test(self):
        return self.render("test_plugin/test.html", content="Hello Starlight!")
v_appbuilder_view = TestAppBuilderBaseView()
v_appbuilder_package = {"name": "Test View",
                        "category": "Test Plugin",
                        "view": v_appbuilder_view}

class AirflowTestPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "test_plugin"
    appbuilder_views = [v_appbuilder_package]
```

Cloud composer UI kick me over to https://[alpha-numeric].appspot.com/admin/ but I can't seem to find the exposed route for my apps plugin. I’ve tried https://[alpha-numeric].appspot.com/admin/test and https://[alpha-numeric].appspot.com/test

I can get a menu link plugin to show up so I know that i am uploading the files to correct location in the storage bucket.

WHAT AM I MISSING HERE?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood exactly your question, but if you want any sort of webserver plugin to work, you must disable dag serialization as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/dag-serialization#disable).
After the lengthy Composer restart, it'll work both in the flask based and appbuilder based ui. [source](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/dag-serialization#before_you_begin)